# How to convert this solidity view function to javascript?

Tags: javascript, solidity

I want to convert this snippet of `solidity` code to `js` code, which comes from:

https://github.com/ensdomains/reverse-records/blob/6ef80ba0a445b3f7cdff7819aaad1efbd8ad22fb/contracts/ReverseRecords.sol#L48

```
    // implement this in javascript.
    function node(address addr) private pure returns (bytes32) {
        return keccak256(abi.encodePacked(ADDR_REVERSE_NODE, sha3HexAddress(addr)));
    }

    function sha3HexAddress(address addr) private pure returns (bytes32 ret) {
        addr;
        ret; // Stop warning us about unused variables
        assembly {
            let lookup := 0x3031323334353637383961626364656600000000000000000000000000000000

            for { let i := 40 } gt(i, 0) { } {
                i := sub(i, 1)
                mstore8(i, byte(and(addr, 0xf), lookup))
                addr := div(addr, 0x10)
                i := sub(i, 1)
                mstore8(i, byte(and(addr, 0xf), lookup))
                addr := div(addr, 0x10)
            }

            ret := keccak256(0, 40)
        }
    }
}
```

`sub`, `div`, `mstore8` are solidity built-in function:  (https://solidity-cn.readthedocs.io/zh/develop/assembly.html )

```
mstore8(p, v)   means:      mem[p] := v & 0xff
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would have been much better to see a sample of what you've been able to come up with, and please try to include that whenever you can.

However, I do believe this may be what you're after. I had written something similar for a personal project sometime back.

```js
import { utils } from "ethers";

const ADDR_REVERSE_NODE =
  "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"; // Replace with the actual value

const LOOKUP_ADDRESS =
  "0x3031323334353637383961626364656600000000000000000000000000000000"; // Replace with the actual value

function getNode(addr) {
  return utils.keccak256(
    utils.concat([ADDR_REVERSE_NODE, sha3HexAddress(addr)])
  );
}

function sha3HexAddress(addr) {
  let hexAddress = "";

  for (let i = 40; i > 0; i--) {
    hexAddress +=
      LOOKUP_ADDRESS[parseInt(addr.slice(i * 2, i * 2 + 2), 16) & 0xf];
    addr = addr.slice(0, i * 2);
  }

  return utils.keccak256(hexAddress);
}
```